# Missing carriage return in rendered page using MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, carriage-return, page-break

I have a problem with my Master page, I have this code:

```
$('.datepicker').click(function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker').css('zIndex', '1000');
});
//Fin de bloque para IE7

$('#wrapper').css({ position: "", visibility: "" });
```

But when the page is rendered, this is the result:

```
$('.ui-datepicker').css('zIndex', '1000');
});
//Fin de bloque para IE7$('#wrapper').css({ position: "", visibility: "" });
$('#wrapper').fadeIn(1000);
```

After the text IE7, the page lost the carriage return and put the two words together. Making the page break.

This problem does not occur on all pages that use the master page, only in some pages.

I tried to remove the compression in the ISS but doesn't solve the problem.

Press Ctrl+F5 and nothing. And in different browsers is the same result.

Someone have any solution?

Comment: Try pasting the code into Notepad, then back into your view.

Comment: try to remove the comment. Clean the browse cache

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a newline in there instead of some other invisible character? Perhaps, you copied the snippet from an HTML page, resulting in [a Unicode NEL character (Next Line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode)? Javascript displays it as a newline but considers it whitespace. It's not only that people would have noticed if there was a bug, the rest of your Javascript in the same file wouldn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Add a semi colon after IE7 or before $('#wrapper'). The semi colon should help terminate the code block.

```
//Fin de bloque para IE7;

$('#wrapper').css({ position: "", visibility: "" });
```

or

```
 //Fin de bloque para IE7
 ;   
 $('#wrapper').css({ position: "", visibility: "" });
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you copied the comment from a web page or other source that used a Unicode NEL character (U+0085) instead of a CR or CR+LF as a line separator. Unicode defines [various characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) apart from CR and LF  that act as line separators and Javascript treats some of them as newlines, some whitespace.

This isn't far fetched, as HTML ignores newlines and some blog engines replace newlines with other Unicode characters to preserve formatting without introducing HTML markup in code snippets.

A Unicode editor (ie almost all of them) would display NEL, LS and PS characters as newlines but browsers would treat the NEL character as whitespace, resulting in the line you posted.

The only way to notice the difference would be to force the editor to display paragraph marks, in which case NEL would appear as "…" `&#x85;`